# Spacing inbetween letters and numbers

Tags: python, json, filter

So basically, I'm trying to write a filter where I can separate numbers and letters from my dictionary and have a space inbetween them. So for instance `12346 S` `12346 Q`.

```
def check_if_works():
    dict_info = {}
    dict_info['1234'] = "test"
    dict_info['12456s'] = "test"
    dict_info['12456q'] = "test"
    dict_info['12456b'] = "test"
    dict_info['123456'] = "test"
    dict_info['asdftes'] = "test"
    dict_info['asdftess'] = "test"
    dict_info['asdftessd'] = "test"
    arr = []
    for key,value in dict_info.iteritems():
        if key.isalpha() or key.isdigit():
            pass
        #print key
        else:
            print key
```

Answer (score 0):

No need for a list of dictionaries, you want to fill and dump the new_dict directly.

Also, there's no need for try/except (which does not work because `str.isalpha()` does never throw exceptions), you should just combine checks to test that it contains only letters or numbers (`isalnum()`) and that it does not contain either only letters (`isalpha()`) or only numbers (`isdigit()`).

Then you also don't write the file once per iteration step over the original dictionary, but only once in the end to dump the entire result dictionary.

```
new_dict = {}

for key,value in dict_info.iteritems():
    check = key.isalnum() and not (key.isalpha() or key.isdigit())

    new_dict[insert_spaces(key)] = value
    print (key, ":", value)

with open('output.json', 'wb') as outfile:
    json.dump(new_dict, outfile, indent=4)
```

The function `insert_spaces` you need to insert a space between digit+letter or letter+digit looks like this:

```
import re
def insert_spaces(key):
    return re.sub(r'(\D)(\d)', r"\1 \2", re.sub(r'(\d)(\D)', r"\1 \2", key))
```

---

Alternatively you could replace that whole code with a dictionary comprehension (since Python 2.7):

```
with open('output.json', 'wb') as outfile:
    json.dump({ insert_spaces(key): dict_info[key] for key in dict_info if key.isalnum() and not (key.isalpha() or key.isdigit()) }, outfile, indent=4)
```

Or nicer formatted by extracting the check condition into a lambda function:

```
check_key = lambda key: key.isalnum() and not (key.isalpha() or key.isdigit())
with open('output.json', 'wb') as outfile:
    json.dump({ insert_spaces(k): dict_info[k] for k in dict_info if check_key(k) }, 
              outfile, indent=4)
```

Comment: Hey, how would I split my letters and numbers so I have space on both.

Comment: @Benji Added a function you can use for that. Note that it requires you to import the `re` module.

Comment: Sweet. I have one last question. So bascially, Let's say I have key such as CS 10, CS 70. So What I'd like to do is pass if the first few characters are same. If they are not same then keep adding it to the list. So like comparing two words.